# How can I make this code short and easy to read?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I have more than 10 lines like this and I want to echo just 5 rows per page this is my code.

```
$c  = mysqli_fetch_field_direct;
$c1 = $c($result,2)->name;
$c2 = $c($result,3)->name;
$c3 = $c($result,4)->name; 
//$cn,...;

echo "$row[2]" ; echo "$c1[2]";
echo "$row[3]" ; echo "$c1[3]"; 
//echo "$row[n]" , ...;
```

Before this code I have this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE id = '$_POST[text]'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

If ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

 //the 10 lines of codes above

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to loop through these elements:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE id = '$_POST[text]'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

If ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

   for($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++){
      $c  = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i)->name;
      echo $row[$i] ; echo $c[$i];
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes , if last line write like this echo $row[$i] ; echo $c;

Comment: Ok. I thought that you were the one who downvoted the answer.

Comment: No!!! Your code is perfect and help me a lot, but i don't know why someone downvoted the answer..

Comment: Somehow, after it was marked as correct answer it was removed and downvoted. That's weird!! Happy that I helped anyway.